# Is there a problem in using hooks inside components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have my main `<App/>` and inside my app I'm using multiple `useState` hooks.
Inside my app I'm also using a component called `<Component/>`.

Inside this Component I'm using a couple of `useEffect` hooks, so there goes my question, is placing the `useEffect` hooks inside the Component file a good practice? If not, if you need to have a `useEffect` hook inside a Component. How would you accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the `useEffect` hook inside any component in your app.

I am assuming you are referring to the problem where the use of `useState` and `useEffect` hooks can cause your component to render infinitely. This happens when you update the state inside the `useEffect` hook, and that hook either has

- no dependencies, or
- depends on the state that you just updated

To avoid this, simply make sure your effect does not depend on the state you are updating.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your setup is just fine. This is the beauty of hooks, is that you can use them in any function component, and as many as you want!